# Laravel & Blade PHP - How would I call a Laravel Blade directive dynamically?

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-blade

Is it possible to use a variable as the call to a Laravel Blade directive?

For my menu system, I've defined a component and I would like to be able to set the visibility of a link in the component. I have created numerous Blade directives (`staff`, `admin`, `client`, etc.) which check a user's role.

My component definition looks like this:

```
@component('components.primaryMenu', [
    'items' => [
        [
            'route' => route('some.uri'),
            'visibility' => ['staff', 'client'],
            'label' => 'Item 1',
        ],
        [
            'route' => route('another.uri'),
            'visibility' => ['everyone'],
            'label' => 'Item 2',
        ],
    ]
])@endcomponent
```

What I would like to do is:

```
<ul class="nav">
    @foreach($items as $item)
        @foreach($item['visibility'] as $visibility)
            @{{ $visibility }}  // Should interpolate to @staff / @client
                // Link stuff in here
            @end{{ $visibility }} // Should interpolate to @endstaff / @endclient
        @endforeach
    @endforeach
</ul>
```

When I run this code I get `"Invalid argument supplied for foreach()"`. I'm guessing because the `@{{ $visibility }}` declarations are throwing off the parser.

My Blade directives are defined in a service provider and look like this:

```
    Blade::if('staff', function () use ($user) {
        return $user->isType('staff');
    });

    Blade::if('client', function () use ($user) {
        return $user->isType('client');
    });
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with `@{{ $visibility }}`?
What is '@staff / @client'?

Comment: @staff is a Blade directive. It checks the role of the authorised user. https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/blade#extending-blade

Comment: Oh right, now I understand; you are trying to interpolate the visibility and have it evaluated as a directive. What kind of directive is it? A custom one or an if statement?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to interpolate. They are custom directives.

Comment: Okay, please add the code for your custom directives.